# Facebook login shows a blank page after giving permission on Windows Phone

Tags: facebook, mobile

I am building a mobile site where a user has to be able to login with his facebook account as described on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/. It works on Iphone and Android devices but on Windows Phone it does not. This is what happens:

1. When I press the login button I get the facebook page where I have to give permission to use my facebook account.
2. After I give promission, it redirects to "*https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request*" and a blank page is shown. On Android the "window.FB.login" callback is called (see code below) where I can get the info and redirect the user but on Windows Phone it only shows that blank page. When I go to my facebook page, my site is registered in the app list. So the registration did work correctly.

The same thing happens when I try to login on the example page: http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hello/.

Does anyone know how to make it work on Windows Phone? And is it even possilble? Because I found a lot of sites where this happens.

This is my code: (Once again this works on Android and Iphone devices).

```
    var fbApi = {
      init: function () {
      $.getScript(document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js', function () {
        if (window.FB) {
            window.FB.init({
                appId: MY_APP_ID,
                status: true,
                cookie: true,
                xfbml: false,
                oauth: true,
            });

        }
    });
    },
    login: function () {
    /// <summary>
    /// Login facebook button clicked
    /// </summary>
    log("login facebook button clicked");

    if (window.FB) {

        //Windows phone does not enter this method, Android and Iphone do
        window.FB.login(function (response) {

            if (response.status) {
                log('it means the user has allowed to communicate with facebook');

                fbAccessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                window.FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                    //get information of the facebook user.
                    loginService.subscribeSocialUser(response.id, response.first_name, response.last_name, fbAccessToken, "", "FaceBook", fbSucces, fbFail);

                });
            } else {
                log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');

            }
        },
        { scope: 'email'
        });
    }

}
};
```

Comment: Having the same issue, don't know if client side Javascript SDK works on devices that are presented the WAP login dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in an other way as described here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/